# How to know what is causing my React Native component to mount?

Tags: react-native

I have a ScreenOne component that has a  of  that when pressed navigate to ScreenTwo.

Trying to debug a "Can only update a mounted or mounting component" yellowbox warning, I attached a `console.log("I was mounted!")` on ScreenTwo's `componentDidMount`.

I quickly realized that this component (ScreenTwo) is ALSO being mounted when clicking on the 'back' arrow to return to ScreenOne, one or two seconds after ScreenOne is back on the screen.

So it goes like this:

1. ScreenOne
2. Click on any element
3. ScreenTwo loads and I was mounted! appears in the console
4. I click on the back arrow in header
5. ScreenOne is back on the screen
6. A second or two later, I was mounted! appears again in the console, and the YellowBox pops up letting me know that "Can only update a mounted or mounting component". Please check the code for ScreenTwo.

So how can I know find out why SreenTwo is being mounted again, after returning to ScreenOne?

Comment: You might need to expose an environment for testing, [here](https://snack.expo.io)

Comment: React-Native uses React's environment to handle all JavaScript side rendering (dom tree,...). Through this fact i guess you can use all provided lifecycle methods: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html - There you can use the UPDATING methods to fetch a re-render/updating of the components